# How to setup Paperclip and associations for multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models which should have images associated to them:

```
Program.rb
Episode.rb
Gallery.rb
```

Any of them needs to have different image sizes. For example:

```
Program -> 100x100 , 250x400 , 500x400
Episode -> 222x450 , 210x330 , 1000x1200
Gallery -> 100x100 , 500x400 , 1000x1200
```

Firstly, I thought a `polymorphic` association of a `Picture` model `has_attached_file` (Paperclip's helper) can be sufficient. Just like this:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :imageable, :polypmorphic=> :true
has_attached_file :image, :styles => {... :program1 => "100x100>", :program2 => "250x400>", :episode1=>"222x450" , :episode2=>"210x330" , :gallery1=>"100x100" , :gallery2=>"500x400" ....  }
# There are almost 10 different styles for different models...
end
```

By this way, I could use images just like this:

```
@program.pictures.first.image[:program1]
@episode.pictures.second.image[:episode2]
..
.
```

But I don't think that it's efficient? Is it?

*What is the best strategy to handle this kind of a need?*

***How should I build up my associations and Paperclip?***

***For example, is it better to set paperclip for each of models?***

I thought collecting all images inside one table would be a good practise?

What do you think?

This should be a common question in fact? Isn't it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't put an attachment on a polymorphic model unless they all needed exactly the same dimensions. Even then, I still probably wouldn't. Some people have business needs that says all their images should be in one table, though, so their choices may be different.

But in your case it doesn't sound like it. I would definitely put your attachments directly on the given models. The most you need for an attachment is one column (though you can have more). And what is your `Imageable` class doing? It's really just holding data, not behavior (the behavior is really inside Paperclip and relates to persistence more than your business logic, and so should be treated like AR).

Finally, uploading one image to the `Episode` model would require 9 extra transformations, meaning 9 other invocations of `convert`, and 9 extra file saves (pretty slow if we're talking  network storage) that all have to happen during the request, leaving the user waiting.

Comment: Thank you very much for considering my mail and answering the question Jon. I appriciate it.